# Sum up dynamically generated fields

Tags: php

I have created a script that populates fields of a table dynamically using php. If you look at the snippet of code below, I have hit a brick wall now that I want to add all `$sub_total` to create a `$total_cost`. Not sure if I am explaining this well but any direction would be much appreciated.

```
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

            // Calculate hours done per day

            $hrs_done = $row['time_out'] - $row['time_in'];

            if($hrs_done > $row['con_hr']){$hrs = $hrs_done;}
            else{$hrs = $hrs_done;}

            // echo out results into a table

            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">' . $hrs . '</td>';
            echo '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">' . $row['rate'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">'?>

           // Multiply hrs by rate to get sub total charge for day    

           <?php $sub_total = $hrs * $row['rate'];
           echo $sub_total ;
           ?>

             <?php '</td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    // close table>
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should look for tutorials that use `mysqli` or `PDO` for database access, as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Second this problem is as easy as just adding up the subtotal items as you iterate through the loop

```
$grand_total = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
       // your other code omitted for clarity

       $sub_total = $hrs * $row['rate'];
       $grand_total += $sub_total;
       echo $sub_total ;

       // more code
}
echo $grand_total;
```

Comment: Perfect...absolutely makes sense. You just saved me at least 4hrs. I'll take your advise and check out mysqli and PDO. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desired behaviour correctly.
During the loop add each `$sub_total` to `$total_cost` and `echo` this after you've completed the `while` loop

```
<?php

    $total_cost = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        $sub_total = $hrs * $row['rate'];
        $total_cost += $sub_total;
    } 

    echo "Total cost: " . $total_cost;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IF/ELSE block leads to one and the same result in both conditions. Is that the desired result?

On the other hand, I'm not sure, if I understood you correct, but if I did, here's my answer.

Since you want to recieve all the $sub_total, you need all the other vars which have built $sub_total:

They are:

```
$hrs = $hrs_done = $row['time_out'] - $row['time_in']
$row['rate'];
```

If you try with the SUM() MySQL function, you will recieve the sum of the mentioned columns:

```
SELECT sum(time_out) as 'sum_time_out', sum(time_in) as 'sum_time_in', sum(rate) as 'sum_rate' FROM myTable;

$hrs_sum = $hrs_done_sum = $row['sum_time_out'] - $row['sum_time_in'];
$stotal_cost = $hrs)sum * $row['sum_rate'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the while loop creates a new variable $subtotal that you want to add to your constant variable $total.

so within the loop you can add $subtotal to $total and echo the $total after the while loop exits

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
  // your code
  $total = $total + $subtotal; // shorthand is -  $total += $subtotal.
} 

echo $total;
```